# What is the term for solving more complex problems by building off of simpler problems?

Tags: single-word-requests

A few years ago, I watched a video about learning through intuitive leaps by learning simple rules first.

The part I remember was talking about Mario Galaxy. When Mario entered a new land, he would be presented with a very simple puzzle to continue forward. As an unreal example, the first puzzle showed that jumping on a certain box would make some squares on a checkerboard solid and others ghosted. So you jump on the box to make a path across. The next puzzle took it a step further; there are multiple boxes and each one worked specific squares so you learned which boxes worked what squares. Next puzzle, you would have to turn on certain squares and turn off others. Then the final puzzle it added a 3rd dimension; not only a flat checker board, but some squares became walls you needed to turn off to pass through.

All of this is done by learning simple rules first and then applying them to increasingly harder puzzles.

Other examples of this concept would be "The Witness" and "Lemmings" video games.

In the video I saw, this concept had a clear, single word name. But I cannot remember that name. So I'm hoping that someone here knows that concept.

It is *entirely possible* that, since this was talking about Mario and its design, the word wasn't English. However I'm fairly certain it is.

Comment: *Elaboration* might work.

Comment: I want to say that such games are *progressive* or *iterative*, but it's not clear to me exactly what sense is being looked for here.

Comment: Can you please provide a sentence indicating how you would use this word? You've requested a single word, but it's not completely clear if you mean a word to use together with "learning", as in "we mastered the game through [something] learning", or a word that itself implies learning, as in "we mastered the game through [something]".

Answer (score 1):

I believe the word that you are looking for is [***cumulative***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cumulative)

> #### Cumulative:
>
> Increasing by successive additions

Or more specifically the concept of 'cumulative learning' which refers to an accumulation of knowledge and abilities over time which leads to a better understanding of how to complete certain tasks.

Edit to add more references as requested in comments -

More Clearly

> Cumulative learning consolidates the knowledge one has obtained through experiences, allowing it to be reproduced and exploited for subsequent learning situations through cumulative interaction between prior knowledge and new information.

Taken from - 
Lee, JungMi (1 January 2012). "Cumulative Learning". In Seel, Prof Dr Norbert M. (ed.). Encyclopedia of the Sciences of Learning. Springer US. pp. 887–893. doi:10.1007/978-1-4419-1428-6_1660. ISBN 978-1-4419-1427-9.

Comment: Answers without references are baseless.

Comment: @NoamanAli I would have hoped that the merriam-webster dictionary would be considered a valid reference. If you have a better suggestion for a reference please inform me

Comment: My question is where have you included reference? Giving out answers without a basis on ELU is discouraged, because they give rise to inane answers. Also, the word 'cumulative' doesn't necessarily imply a 'developmental transition.' This word is far from it. The question asks for a progressive development.

Comment: @NoamanAli my answer already a hyperlink to the merriam-webster site from where I have take the definition I have provided. (This seems to be the norm looking at the numerous answers I have seem on this site) and while the word 'cumulative' does not imply a 'developmental transition' the question does not ask for a term for 'developmental transition' further more I again have clarified that the  term 'cumulative learning' would better fit the situation or even 'cumulative knowledge'

Comment: You just edited the answer. And what the question seeks clearly seems to fly over your head. It's a no-brainer to comprehend just from the question that once you solve simple problems, you'd advance to a much higher level. Read the question again. What else, if not 'progression'?

Comment: @NoamanAli English is not a language where if one word applicable others are not, furthermore my edit (as mentioned in the answer) was done to satisfy your request for more references. If you find my answer unsatisfactory you are free to add your own instead of jumping to ad hominem comments.

Comment: You need to understand that you aren't doing a favour by adding those references. It is like a mandation done to maintain the standard of the website. And as far as I tell, there really isn't a word that can limn this act in question. So, instead of telling others what to write and what not to, get hold of the nearest dictionary and learn more about the word, and how it's used. It would keep unnecessary/obfuscating answers from popping up.